# How do I get my Virgin Media wireless internet to work on Crunchbang linux?

Tags: wifi, crunchbang

I am struggling to get my internet to work on Linux. I am able to connect to my wireless internet through any other device I choose but my laptop will not find it. I have tried using the hidden connection option but still cannot find it. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: So you can't get the laptop to join your wireless network? What are you using to try (the network manager applet that comes with gnome)?

Comment: um im using the basic that comes with the OS yes, no fancy add ons or anything like that. at the moment i have had to connect my phone to my wireless then use a usb tether from the phone to the laptop to get on to the internet. ass backwards i know but is working for the time being

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable `non-free` in your `sources.list` then install `compat-drivers`.

Answer (score -1):

(in my case broadcom)

just copy+paste `brcm` directory in `lib/firmware` in crunchbang.
You can get that `brcm` directory in Kali Linux or other distro in same place `lib/firmware`